# How do i find those documents whose particular fields matches with any other documents(have the same value)

Tags: mongodb

```
{
    _id: "010",
    "email": "abc@gmail.com"
}
{
    _id: "011",
    "email": "abc@gmail.com"
}
```

For example above the two docs have the same email ids

Comment: which type of response you need?
Like 
[{
  "_id" : {
    "email" : "abc@gmail.com"
},
  "uniqueIds" : [
    "010",
    "011"
  ],
  "count" : 2
}]?

Comment: just the ids of those docs which have their email matching with any other document @PrakashHarvani

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').aggregate([{ $group: {
    _id: { name: "$email" },   
    Ids: { $addToSet: "$_id" },
    count: { $sum: 1 } 
  } }, {$match:{count:{$gte:2}}}]);
```